# Stuck with response.flushBuffer

Tags: javascript, java

Can somebody find what is wrong with this code. I've tried to flush the content partially to the client. But it sends data from initial value rather than sending data in chunks.

```
public String execute()
{
    String action = request.getParameter("action");
    try 
    {
        switch(action)
        {
        case "flush":
        response.setContentType(ContentTypeConstants.APP_JSON_UTF8);
        PrintWriter pw = response.getWriter();
            for(int i = 0 ; i < 10; i++)
            {
               JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
               json.put("key", i+"");
               pw.print(json+"");
               response.flushBuffer();  
               Thread.sleep(500);
            }
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {   
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

My script code is

```
var http=getHTTPObject();
http.open("GET", url, true);
http.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8');
http.setRequestHeader("X-Requested-With","XMLHttpRequest");
http.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (http.readyState == 3)
    {
        console.log(http.responseText)
    }
}
http.send();
```

Comment: So what is the problem?  How does this not work?

Comment: `PrintWriter pw = response.getWriter();` should not be in the loop, but I don't think that is the real cause of your problem.

Comment: @StephenC sorry it is a typo error.now it is corrected.

Comment: could you please answer my first questions?

Comment: @StephenC I got only cumulative response in client side.